# How do we know the format of a date submitted by a user?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, tomcat

If e.g. a servlet expects a date from a form submitted by a user, this date will be send as a string as part of the user parameters.
How do we know how to convert this string to date?
I mean the locale could be different. Could be `M/D/Y` or `D/M/Y` etc.
So how can we know this on server side? I assume this is an issue in other languages as well? E.g. scripts on server side?

Comment: The US military requires the format be dd mmm yyyy, e.g. 01 Mar 2013, to eliminate ambiguity

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot:Requires who? The browsers?

Comment: The form fields for websites made by the military or by its contractors, e.g. the dropdown boxes for month will have {Jan, Feb, Mar, ...} etc instead of e.g. {01, 02, 03, ...}; usually if a website uses mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy then this is made clear on the form fields so that the user won't be confused, but once the data is read by the server (assuming it's kept as a string instead of converted to UTC or whatever) then it can become ambiguous if the data context is somehow lost, whereas dd/mmm/yyyy never becomes ambiguous

Answer (score 1):

You can't know for sure. You have to make assumption based on locale, or you need to specify a particular order.  A date like `01/02/12` could be 12th Feb 1901 or 2001, or 1st feb 1912 or 2012 or 2nd of Jan 1912 or 2012.  There is no way to know from the format.

BTW ISO-8601 format is y/m/d order.

Comment: So if we use a graphical widget in the html page e.g. `jQuery` it will send the date according to the client's locale but on server we can not know the client locale? So using such a widget is useless?

Comment: A date without a locale is useless.  I am surprised this cannot be fixed, but it's something you would have to do at at the JavaScript side.

Comment: Well from a `jquery-ui` input I am seeing: `05/20/2013`

Comment: This is fine for most days of the year.  It won't be so fine for `06/07/2013` and dates like it. If the Javascript can send the locale it should (I would be surprised if it cannot)  If this fails you could send a known date to the server to derive the locale. e.g. Send 15th Jan 2040 in the current locale, from this you can determine the order.

Comment: What about `HttpServletRequest#getLocale`? Just noticed this.

Comment: It may be safe to assume this will be sent and is the same.  I don't know enough about all the browsers you might have to support to know if this is guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

Use a date control in the form where you *dictate* the format, typically based on the user's locale.